# Magento Inserting your block into any place - duplicate issue

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise

I am trying to insert a **phtml** file using **observer** through this code

```
public function insertShippingBlock($observer)
{
    /** @var $_block Mage_Core_Block_Abstract */
    /*Get block instance*/
    $_block              = $observer->getBlock();
    /*get Block type*/
    $_type               = $_block->getType();


    if ($_type == 'checkout/onepage_shipping') {

        $_block->unsetChild('child_branchoptions');
        /*Clone block instance*/
        $_child = clone $_block;
        /*set another type for block*/
        $_child->setType('core/template');

        $_block->setChild('child_options', $_child);
        /*set child for block*/
        $_block->setTemplate('shipping_method/customoptions.phtml');
    }
}
```

But It's repeating the custom options[image]

"Custom option 1" is repeating twice. Could you please help in this

**customoptions.phtml**

```
<input name="selected" type="radio" name="chooseoption" id="chooseoption" onclick="chooseoption()">Custom Option 1
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('child_options') ?></li></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this event called twice this is simple solution Use `registry`

```
if ($_type == 'checkout/onepage_shipping') {
       if(!Mage::registry('checking'))
    { 
         Mage::register('checking', 'yes'); 
        $_block->unsetChild('child_branchoptions');
        /*Clone block instance*/
        $_child = clone $_block;
        /*set another type for block*/
        $_child->setType('core/template');

        $_block->setChild('child_options', $_child);
        /*set child for block*/
        $_block->setTemplate('shipping_method/customoptions.phtml');
        }
    }
```

Comment: @ Fme Extension -- Still I am facing the same issue. I like to know why the dropdown was not duplicating, only the static content was duplicating.